# 'Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined ' after upgrade to Angular 6 from 5

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After update to @angular/cli:6.0.3 and @angular:6.0.3

My app is not rendered on browser due:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at inherits (inherits_browser.js:5)
    at Object../node_modules/hash-base/index.js (index.js:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
```

My dependencies on package.json are:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "browser-sync":"^2.24.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "primeng": "^5.2.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "sax": "^1.2.4",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "vm": "^0.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "xml2js": "0.4.19",
    "xml2js-es6-promise": "1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"   },
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?